# Storing tree data in a database for fast reading of the whole hierarchy

Tags: c#, database, sql, mongodb, persistence

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class Entity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Entity> Children { get; set; }
    
    public void DoStuff(Data data)
    {
        // stuff
        
        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            child.DoStuff(data);
        }
    }
}
```

And I need to persist this in a database. Available options: MongoDB, SQL server or PostgreSQL.

I was wondering what is the best approach for storing this kind of tree data considering these conditions:

- Read performance is most important when the whole tree is queried - parent with all of its descendants.
- Usually only one child will be present per `Entity` in the `Children` list. But the depth of the tree could be 50-100.
- Once the parent is created I need to be able to add/delete children. But the speed of this operation is not that important.

In JSON data looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "xyz_0",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "xyz_1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "xyz_2",
                    "children": [

                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "xyz_3",
                    "children": [

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

At the moment I'm using MongoDB and storing a single tree per JSON document. And the application code looks something like this:

```
var entity = mongoCollection
    .Find(Builders<Entity>
        .Filter
        .Eq(o => o.Id, parentId))
    .SingleOrDefault();

foreach (var data in GetData(10000))
{
    entity.DoStuff(data);
}
```

But reading a couple of previous posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837906/mongodb-does-document-size-affect-query-performance) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721627/mongodb-one-big-document-or-more-than-one-collection) mentions that it's not such a great idea to store big documents. So I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: What have your benchmarks shown? How does your application perform when using *big documents* versus *many small documents*? And what about *range selection*? ... Can you put identifiers or sort keys on documents that necessary put them "under" their ancestors. `1 -> 1.1 -> 1.1.1` ... `1 -> 1.9 -> 1.9.9` ... `select * from table where sort_key >= 1 and sort_key < 2`?

Comment: There is an algorithm for this in relational but i can't recall the name :/ the basic idea is that you assign anumber to every entity. Non-leaf entities also get two more fields: a `child_min` and `child_max`. You set the fields such that the `number`s of all children are between their parent's `child_min` and `child_max`. To query a (sub)-tree you do `SELECT * FROM entity parent JOIN entity child ON child.number BETWEEN parent.child_min AND parent.child_max`. You have to build the actual tree structure in-memory then, but that's certainly quick with only 100-200 entities in a tree.

Comment: In general, to facilitate retrieval, trees are stored in depth-first order. [Example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). However, when it comes to databases, the main concern is the need for tree rebalancing (tree rotation), the frequency and the workload where such long operations must be performed, and how much write amplification may result from such operations.

Comment: If each tree is seldom (never) modified after initial creation, there may be a way to preprocess it into a form that facilitates traversal. If modification happens quite a few times, it may be necessary to consider the performance of modifications.